# Putting more than one variable into a sql statement

Tags: php

I have constructed the following -

```
`$format_$game_$name_$season`
```

4 variables with underscores between. Should this work, or will it act as one variable?

THankyou

Comment: Why would you need to do this?  First of all, you may be opening yourself to SQL injection.  Second, it seems like your database is quite oddly structured.

Comment: Its because I have a table that is named something like Format_Game_Name_Season.
And i need to get to that using 4 variables when making a query!

Comment: You should probably be using SQL more extensively, if you're making multiple tables for individual formats and games and names and seasons.

Comment: You should consider redesigning your schema.  There should not be a separate table for each game.

Comment: For each league I have been creating a seperate table. A league is something that happens once every 6 months.

Comment: A league should probably be a row in a leagues table, then you could merge your... whatever goes in those many league tables... into one table, giving each row the league ID number of the league it belongs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That **wont work**, but not because it'll act as one variable.

First, you need to use double quotes. Backticks wont interpret at all and variables wont be expanded in a single quoted string. Further reading: [String Parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Furthermore, when double quoting your string it'll be interpreted as `$format_ . $game_ . $name_ . $season`. That is, PHP will be thinking the three first variables end with an underscore. You'll have to do either `$format . '_' . $game . '_' . $name . '_' . $season` or `"{$format}_{$game}_{$name}_{$season}"`.

Answer (score 3):

A quick test indicates that, <s>for reasons I can not fathom</s>, your interpolation will not work as you expect it to.

```
<?php
    $xa = 'x';
    $xb = 'y';
    $xc = 'z';
    echo "$xa_$xb_$xc";
?>
```

The output of the above script in PHP 5.3 is `z`, since it reads `$xa_` (which is empty), `$xb_` (which is empty), and `$xc` (which is `z`).

If you use braces for interpolation, however, you should get the desired output.

```
<?php
    $xa = 'x';
    $xb = 'y';
    $xc = 'z';
    echo "${xa}_${xb}_${xc}";
?>
```

The output of the above script in PHP 5.3 is `x_y_z`, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

### Useful Information

With backtick (``` `` ```) delimiters, your variable will be blank.

With single quotes (`'`), it'll be interpreted literally.

With double quotes (`"`), you should get the variable interpolation (in most cases expect the case described in your question). You can use braces too for readability and some situations where it won't work without them, i.e `{$var['key']}`.

Comment: Though the syntax note is important, this answer doesn't seem to address the initial question of whether or not the interpolation will act as the OP wants it to... Are you just saying that it will?

Comment: @Matchu I'm saying as long as he surrounds that string with double quotes, it should substitute the variables. I think it should help him.

Answer (score 1):

> Should this work, or will it act as
>   one variable?

It will not, no.

1) You should use [PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html) for database access (I'm required to say this!)

With that out of the way:

2) Backticks are [execution operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

3) Variables can be encased in braces: `"{$format}_{$game}_{$name}_{$season}"`

4) Some databases use the underscore as a special character so it may need to be escaped